# How to Inject Javascript code during HTTP call

Tags: javascript

I want to inject some javascript code during HTTP call before onload function is called. How can i achieve this? Is this even possible? I have achieved this using Chrome extension but I want some other method to inject the code which works on all other browsers. Something like injecting through URL bar while opening the page. This injection should work on all sites i open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another neat way to do it is to **have the request go through a proxy**. The proxy can inject the JS by modifying the source before it arrives to the client. This is how most ad-supported (ad-injecting) proxies do it.

But then, it's a security issue. That's why, same as having to tell the user to install an extension, you'd have to tell the user to use the proxy. Otherwise, it's a no-go.

---

Yet another way to do it is to have the owners of the site embed a script that points to a permanent path. Behind that path, you write any script, which may include one that loads some more scripts.

It can be as short as:

```
<script src="path/to/a/permanent/location"></script>
```

This is typically how publicly served APIs work, like Google. Behind their permanent path is a script that loads all the APIs you need. But, like I said in the previous section, you need permission, this time in the form of having the webmaster embed the script on the page.

Comment: I need to explore the first option. It looks neat.